# web service throws error/exception on POST request

Tags: java, ajax, reactjs, web-services

In my code (posted below), I am sending a json array to my Java web service from my ReactJS client using ajax query. The web service then stores that array into a file. But I am getting 500 http error code. Please tell what can be the issue in my code?

**Error:**

[image]

**Client:**

```
saveChanges(newRecordsArray) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/myService/save",
            data: newRecordsArray, //json array containing records
            dataType: "json",
            contentType:'application/json',
            async: false
        });
    }
```

**Server:**

```
@POST
    @Path("/save")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveNewRecords(JSONArray newRecordsArray) {
        try {
            File recordsFile = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\myJSON.txt");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(recordsFile);
            fileWriter.write(newRecordsArray.toString());
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return Response.status(200).entity(newRecordsArray.toString()).build();
    }
```

Comment: why don't you print or log the exception thrown ?

Comment: let me know what it prints

Comment: 500 is a Internal Server Error... Does the file "myJSON.txt" exist in "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\" ?

Comment: @UsmanRana how can I print server's eception at client side?

Answer (score 0):

I think the address is wrong. Have you tried to invoke the service using postman, or other external tools? Does it works? If it does, it should be a problem related to the payload. Try to intercept the outgoing HTTP request.